# Error about UUID UUID_GENERATE_V

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, uuid

After migrating to a new db server, I find these errors :

```
[ERR] 9> create or replace function "public"."uuid_generate_v1mc"()
returns "pg_catalog"."uuid" AS '$libdir/uuid-oosp'.'uuid_generate_v1mc'
Language c **volatile** strict
COST 1
[ERR] 9> Error: permission denied for language c
[DTF] 10> uuid_generate_v3: Getting function structure
[DTF] 10> uuid_generate_v3: Create function

[ERR] 10> create or replace function "public"."uuid_generate_v3"("namespace" uuid, "name" text)
returns "pg_catalog"."uuid" AS '$libdir/uuid-oosp'.'uuid_generate_v3'
Language c **immutable** strict
COST 1
[ERR] 10> Error: permission denied for language c
[DTF] 11> uuid_generate_v4: Getting function structure
[DTF] 11> uuid_generate_v4: Create function

[ERR] 11> create or replace function "public"."uuid_generate_v4"()
```

I check using `SELECT * from pg_extension` on the Old Server, it does not exist but It is never been a problem there.
I check on the new server, and it does not exist too but suddenly becomes a problem.

Questions :

1. What is causing the error?
2. How do I solve and avoid this kind of error?
3. I do `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";`. How do i check if the function works correctly?

I am using postgresql 12 and Ubuntu 20.04
Please kindly help. Thank you

Comment: "*What is causing the error*"  - someone un-installed that extension. To solve it install the extension using `create extension`. You need to login to the database using the superuser (typically `postgres`)

Comment: Perhaps you migrated from a server that was ancient enough to not yet have extensions.

Comment: Btw: if you had migrated to a more recent version (15, 14) you wouldn't need the extension to begin with, because starting with Postgres 13, it has [gen_random_uuid()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) built-in